# Auto mapper skip item if a child have NULL value

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, automapper, in-memory-database

I have a problem in data transformation with [AutoMapper](http://automapper.org/) that completely skip parent class after mapping to [Dto](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_transfer_object) when a member of parent is **NULL**.

**Parent class:**

```
public class Parent : BaseEntity
{   
    public string Something { get; set; }

    public string SomthingElse { get; set; }

    public Member Member { get; set; }
}
```

**Parent Dto class:**

```
public class ParentDto : BaseEntity
{   
    public string Something { get; set; }

    public Member Member { get; set; }
}
```

**Member class:**

```
public class Member : BaseEntity
{
    public string MemberName { get; set; }

    public int? SomethingId { get; set; }
}
```

When we mapped parent class to [Dto](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_transfer_object) and if `Member` was not **NULL** all thing work like a charm but problem is when the `Member` is **NULL** parent model completely skipped in result. I have no exception or error, just parent class that have **NULL** `Member` was skipped in results.

**Result generated by LINQ**:

```
var results = await query
    .Skip(pageNumber * pageSize)
    .Take(pageSize)
    .ProjectTo<ParentDto>()
    .ToArrayAsync(ct);
```

**Mapping created like this:**

```
CreateMap<Parent, ParentDto>();
```

**Packages version:**

> **AutoMapper** **6.1.1**
>
> **Microsoft.AspNetCore** **2.0.0**
>
> **Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.InMemory** **2.0.0**

Did you have any idea that help me what is the problem and how can i solve it?

Comment: Can you show the `Member` model (class and fluent configuration if any).

Comment: @IvanStoev Yes. question is updated.

Comment: I guess `Model` is what you call `Member` in other places. Anyway, can't reproduce, the problem is most likely in `query` rather than in AutoMapper. What happens if you remove `.ProjectTo`, are you getting correct result?

Comment: @IvanStoev Yes i log the length of result without the `.ProjectTo` and i get the correct length.

Comment: @IvanStoev I mistakenly write name of `Model` instead of `Member`. sorry for confusing. question was updated.

Comment: Ok, but I'm getting correct results in both cases. The last thing, can we see the `query` as well? And EFC and AM versions.

Comment: @IvanStoev My `EFC` is in memory with version **2.0.0** and `AutoMapper` with version **6.1.1**. my query is: `IQueryable<Parent> query = Entities;` and `Entities` is my `dbContext`.

Comment: Hmm, exactly the same as in my test except that I'm using SqlServer (LocalDB). Well, I'm afraid there is nothing more I can do without repro. Good luck.

Comment: @IvanStoev Thank for your care. i think the problem goes from in memory database. thank you again.